# PC freezing and locking up

Tags: freeze, crash

I installed additional 8 Gb of RAM on a system recently. Everything was running fine before I observed that the system randomly froze, I don't know what the proper term is, but the screen just hangs up on a static frame, and the PC, just hangs up. And it usually happens when I am playing games on it; 
I took following steps to check what is wrong:
Updated all the drivers
Clean OS install 
Removed the newly installed RAM sticks
Removed the old ones and checked with the new ones only 
Removed any additional peripheral 
Memtest, with no errors 
Check disk, no errors
System file verification, no errors

One thing strange thing happens, when the system hangs up, my keyboard just powers down, and it's a Logitech G510, and with power downs I mean that it goes blank, and that is rare since even during crashes, usually the keyboard backlight is there.

The specs of PC are: 
Windows 7 professional x64
Intel core i3 3rd generation(3240)
Intel Z75 based m-ATX motherboard(Intel DZ75ML-45K)
Nvidia 550ti 
2*2gb ram sticks @1333(corsair)
2*4gb ram sticks @1333(transcend)
Microsoft wireless combo 
Logitech G510 keyboard 
450w cooler master smps 
Htpc cabinet

The temperatures are within range during load; they rarely cross 70C 
GPU stress test sometimes crashes the system, and sometimes goes on for hours without any crash.

Any guess what might be wrong? 
(Sorry for not being able to give exact specifications of PC, and I hope this is the right section for asking such questions)

Comment: So after a clean reinstall and having the newly added RAM removed, it still freezes?

Comment: Yup, it does, and that is bothering me, why when everything is back as it was before

Comment: System "Freezes" are not memory problems thats normally caused by HDD problems.  Time to replace your HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound But the HDD was working fine before, and all the trouble happened only after I installed the new RAM sticks

Comment: @Siddharth - The problem also remains after you installed Windows again which points to a hardware problem not a software problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Might be true, but how and why, and where, since RAM upgrades are not known to cause any permanent hardware damage

Answer (score 1):

If your mouse pointer freezes, it's most likely RAM, graphics card, motherboard or power.  If most/all stuff freezes, but the mouse keeps working, then it's most likely a hard drive problem.

You've proven it's (most likely) a hardware problem by reinstalling and seeing the same problem, so now it's time to start troubleshooting your hardware.

1. Visually inspect and make sure you didn't knock anything out-of-whack when you installed the RAM (heat sinks, etc.).
2. Run memory tests (memTest86+) for a couple *days* straight.
3. If they come up clean then start swapping hardware for known-good parts until you find the culprit.  Start with the power supply.

Comment: Seems like that might be the possible course of action, but I have checked everything internally, no loose cables, no improperly installed hardware, and even power rating of each connection is normal,  so just out of curiosity, what can go wrong with simple ram installation

Comment: Static electricity for one. Coincidence for another.

Comment: and bad luck can be another, I have replaced the HDD with a backup one and now I am running Memtest for like two days, let's see what happens.

Comment: I used "coincidence" instead of "bad luck" but you get my meaning. :)  Good luck!

Comment: One thing I would like to ask about is that does HDD failures ceases any power to USB devices, since my USB devices just turn off during crash